# Can I assume sizeof(GUID)==16 at all times?

Tags: windows, guid, sizeof

The definition of GUID in the windows header's is like this:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
unsigned long Data1;
unsigned short Data2;
unsigned short Data3;
unsigned char Data4[ 8 ];
} GUID;
```

However, no packing is not defined. Since the alignment of structure members is dependent on the compiler implementation one could think this structure could be longer than 16 bytes in size.

If i can assume it is always 16 bytes - my code using GUIDs is more efficient and simple.
However, it would be completely unsafe - if a compiler adds some padding in between of the members for some reason.

My questions do potential reasons exist ? Or is the probability of the scenario that sizeof(GUID)!=16 actually really 0.

Comment: Why do you care? Always be safe and use sizeof(). First of all, sizeof() can be evaluated at compile them, and second, simply don't expect anything on your own if it is not explicitly specified. For ages, people expected longint to be 32 bit. Now it is 64 bit on most platforms and code breaks. People expected endianess and then wonder why bytes get swapped. Simply put, don't expect it.

Comment: The C standard does not define the sizeof a pointer.

Comment: The C standard does not define the sizeof a pointer. However, the RFC 4122 defines a GUID as 128-bit number. That's why the question comes up. Furthermore, if you look at other platforms, on linux/mac UUID are defined as 16bytes chars. I can now make a tradeoff: make the code more complicated to handle the case that sizeof(GUID)!=16 or have easy code. In a normal case I would agree with you. However, GUIDs are pretty special. The type is directly used in RPC structures and so on. The slight underspecification of GUID type in the headers makes it an interesting border case.

Comment: @Shi: `sizeof` can't guarantee alignment, e.g. for SSE.

Comment: What are you doing that the GUID comparisons might have a performance impact on your code?

Comment: @jeffamphone: if you write a platform independent wrapper around the GUID. You can just convert pointer's to convert from the wrapper to the guid type. You can also return const references. These things require the same memory layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not official documentation, but perhaps [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/22/9560726.aspx) can ease some of your fears. I think there was another one on a similar topic, but I cannot find it now.

What I want to say is that Windows structures do have a packing specifier, but it's a global setting which is somewhere inside the header files. It's a `#pragma` or something. And it is mandatory, because otherwise programs compiled by different compilers couldn't interact with each other - or even with Windows itself.

Comment: If this would be official documentation. I think then everything would be clear.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. <windows.h> is part of the Windows SDK and by definition is both code and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not zero, it depends on your system. If the alignment is word (4-bytes) based, you'll have padding between the `short`s, and the size will be more than 16.

If you want to be sure that it's 16 - manually disable the padding, otherwise use `sizeof`, and don't assume the value.

Comment: I would think so too. However, but shouldn't this break the complete windows api ? especially the rpc api. ( which typedefs uuid as guid. )

Comment: @JE42 - no, because Windows API is on one system so everything is consistent, and the RPC will probably use streaming (`ntoh`, `hton` etc) alignment.

Answer (score 2):

If I feel I need to make an assumption like this, I'll put a 'compile time assertion' in the code. That way, the compiler will let me know if and when I'm wrong.

If you have or are willing to use Boost, there's a `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` macro that does this.

For my own purposes, I've cobbled together my own (that works in C or C++ with MSVC, GCC and an embedded compiler or two) that uses techniques similar to those described in this article:

- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html

The real tricks to getting the compile time assertion to work cleanly is dealing with the fact that some compilers don't like declarations mixed with code (MSVC in C mode), and that the techniques often generate warnings that you'd rather not have clogging up an otherwise working build. Coming up with techniques that avoid the warnings is sometimes a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on any Windows compiler. Otherwise [`IsEqualGUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680575.aspx) would not work: it compares only the first 16 bytes. Similarly, any other WinAPI function that takes a `GUID*` just checks the first 16 bytes.

Note that you must not assume generic C or C++ rules for `windows.h`. For instance, a byte is always 8 bits on Windows, even though ISO C allows 9 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you write code dependent on the size of someone else's structure, 
warning bells should go off.

Could you give an example of some of the simplified code you want to use?
Most people would just use sizeof(GUID) if the size of the structure was needed.

With that said -- I can't see the size of GUID ever changing.

Comment: The elements themselves may not change, but from one platform to another, the amount of memory used may change.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpc.h>
int main () {
GUID myGUID;
printf("size of GUID is %d\n", sizeof(myGUID));
return 0;
}
```

Got 16.  This is useful to know if you need to manually allocate on the heap.